# Do sql batch in specific time on windows job scheduler

Tags: c#, sql-server, job-scheduling

did anyone have solution on using visual studio to create batch sql running to check two database table are equal or not? ***These two database is not staying on the same machine.***

i plan to use windows job scheduler to do it, please provide me some solution or ways to do it by step, i been scratching for solution for some days, please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Why would you not use SQL Agent for this? how do you define the equality of two tables? What is the problem you're attempting to solve?

Comment: What do you want to compare? data or structure?

Comment: @alroc compare two table are equal or not.

Comment: @ThiagoLoureiro i want to compare data are equal or not

Comment: there is a `tablediff` utility  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/tablediff-utility

Comment: @Sembilan again, why don't you use SQL Server Agent? As for comparing, what do you mean? A simple JOIN between two tables would find all differences. Tables with change tracking would give you the changes directly, no need to check whether they've changed. Change Tracking is available since 2005 for *all* editions, including Express and LocalDB. It's also very lightweight.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i want to try to use a batch to run compare two table from different machine using windows job to run at specific time.

Comment: @Sembilan again, why? SQL Server Agent's job is precisely that - running jobs that execute SQL statements or other steps at specific times. You also didn't explain why you want to do that instead of using change tracking or replication. There are a many efficient ways to find and extract differences. In any case, *did* you try to write a JOIN?

Comment: @Sembilan you can link one server to another if you add it as a Linked Server. Joins though will have to move data from one server to another at some point. The data *has* to end up on the same RAM in order to run comparisons.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for remind me the ram of comparisons.